# Import and Mount ZFS Pool: "dataset does not exist"

Tags: mount, zfs

I am trying to rescue data from a Truenas / FreeNas Pool via Ubuntu. Originally in Truenas from one day to another my Pool wasnt accessible anymore (see this [post](https://www.truenas.com/community/threads/untypical-reboot-loop-and-crashed-pool-how-to-rescue-data-first.90449/)). Actually the system got in a reboot loop, but that isnt the point.

Now in Ubuntu I do see the pool "RaidPool" via

```
sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL
```

Answer ist:

> NAME   FSTYPE       SIZE MOUNTPOINT                   LABEL
> loop0  squashfs    55,5M /snap/core18/1988
> loop1  squashfs    64,8M /snap/gtk-common-themes/1514
> loop2  squashfs    31,1M /snap/snapd/11036
> loop3  squashfs     219M /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/66
> loop4  squashfs    32,3M /snap/snapd/11107
> loop5  squashfs      51M /snap/snap-store/518
> sda    zfs_member   3,7T
> ├─sda1                2G
> └─sda2 zfs_member   3,7T                              RaidPool
> sdb    zfs_member   3,7T
> ├─sdb1                2G
> └─sdb2 zfs_member   3,7T                              RaidPool
> sdc               111,8G
> ├─sdc1 vfat         512M /boot/efi
> ├─sdc2                1K
> └─sdc5 ext4       111,3G /

**Try No 1:**

```
zpool import RaidPool
```

Answer:

```
cannot open 'RaidPool': dataset does not exist
```

**Try No 2:**

```
sudo zpool import RaidPool
```

Answer:

```
cannot import 'RaidPool': pool was previously in use from another system.
Last accessed by  (hostid=99d0d700) at Sun Jan 17 02:50:30 2021
```

**Try No 3-5** (all with same answer):

```
sudo zpool import -f RaidPool
sudo zpool import -o readonly=on RaidPool
sudo zpool import -o readonly=on -f RaidPool
```

Answer:
Nothing happens, the curser just goes on and off. I dont hear the harddrives, I gues nothing is happening from this point, so I close the Terminal after 10 min.

Finally via Ubuntu UI I do see the RaidPool, but when opening it I get the message:
"Error mounting /dev/sda2 at /media/chd/RaidPool: unknown filesystem type 'zfs_Member'

Any ideas, how to import or just read the data in that pool?

Thanks very much upfront!